# HAS ANCESTOR and HAS DESCENDANT clauses in google cloud datastore

Tags: gql, google-cloud-datastore

I'm studying the [Google Cloud Datastore GQL grammar](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference?hl=en#grammar) - specifically the `HAS ANCESTOR` and `HAS DESCENDANT` comparison operators.

Giving the following *Person* entities:

- Amy
- Fred, parent = Amy
- Laura, parent = Amy
- Paul
- Agnes ...

Would the GQL queries below produce the same output?

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE key_name='Fred' HAS ANCESTOR KEY('Person', 'Amy')

SELECT * FROM Person WHERE KEY('Person', 'Amy') HAS DESCENDANT key_name='Fred'
```

If so, I don't understand the existence of HAS DESCENDANT clause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two GQL queries should produce identical results:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY('Person', 'Amy')
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE KEY('Person', 'Amy') HAS DESCENDANT __key__
```

Comment: `Person` shouldn't be in quotes, at least within the console GUI